# ggplot2 - how to not display zero value in rose diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm loading values from .csv to R, which has the following data:

```
   Time   Way       Data1
1     0 Type1   0,0586865
2     1 Type1  0,05674993
3     2 Type1 0,067387033
4     3 Type1 0,064299747
5     4 Type1  0,06241931
6     5 Type1 0,070333988
7     6 Type1  0,07956778
8     7 Type1 0,066797642
9     8 Type1 0,061015998
10    9 Type1 0,050463093
11   10 Type1 0,037412293
12   11 Type1 0,023323042
13   12 Type1 0,021975863
14   13 Type1 0,011787819
15   14 Type1 0,014201516
16   15 Type1 0,023351109
17   16 Type1 0,034689868
18   17 Type1 0,035812518
19   18 Type1 0,034100477
20   19 Type1 0,022312658
21   20 Type1 0,015239966
22   21 Type1 0,017204603
23   22 Type1 0,031209655
24   23 Type1 0,039657592
25    0 Type2        0,01
26    1 Type2        0,02
27    2 Type2           0
28    3 Type2        0,01
29    4 Type2        0,01
30    5 Type2           0
31    6 Type2           0
32    7 Type2           0
33    8 Type2        0,02
34    9 Type2           0
35   10 Type2           0
36   11 Type2        0,01
37   12 Type2           0
38   13 Type2        0,01
39   14 Type2           0
40   15 Type2        0,02
41   16 Type2           0
42   17 Type2        0,01
43   18 Type2           0
44   19 Type2           0
45   20 Type2           0
46   21 Type2        0,01
47   22 Type2           0
48   23 Type2           0
```

As you can see, some of the values from Type2 has value = 0. When I use this data to display to a rose diagram, it shows the zero values which is not supposed.

The following image link shows the output: http://i61.tinypic.com/b81lvq.png

My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)

nameOfDataExcel <- file.path(path, "data.csv")

data <- read.csv(file=nameOfDataExcel,head=TRUE,sep=";")

cols <- c("red","blue") 

p<-ggplot(data, aes(x = data$Time, y=data$Data1, fill=data$Way)) + 
geom_bar(breaks = seq(0,24), width = 1, colour="black", stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
theme_minimal() +  coord_polar(theta = "x") +
scale_x_continuous("", breaks = seq(0, 24), labels = seq(0,24))

p
```

How can I ignore the zero values so they are not shown in the diagram?

Comment: The `0` is there because it appears in `Time` which you've supplied as the x axis. The 0 is nothing to do with the values in `Data1`

Comment: @Phil I think he means that `Type2` bars have height even when their value is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect because the file is being loaded with commas (`,`) separating the digits it's not reading the data in correctly. When I replaced the commas with `.` and imported I my plot did not have values plotted for 0.

Try using `readr` which handles files with comma digit separators gracefully:

```
install.packages("readr")
require("readr")
data <- read_csv2("~/Desktop/data.csv")
```

Assuming your file is delimited by something other than a comma (probably a semi-colon). You should get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your decimal separator is a full stop. Base R `read.*` functions can handle this via the `dec` argument.

In particular, `read.csv2` and `read.delim2` the default argument for `dec` is `,`.

Alternatively, something like

```
read.table("file1.txt", dec=",", sep="\t")
```

should do the trick.